# Problem with Input from Serial Monitor

Tags: serial

I have a piece of code as shown, and I wish to print the value I send using serial monitor along with a message: "Writing data to slave...".

[image]

But everytime I enter a character/number in the serial monitor(like 'a' as shown), the loop runs two times instead of just once. It seems like an extra character(somewhat invisible or null) is being sent along with the typed character.

[image]

If I use the condition (Serial.available()>1)  then the loop runs just once on sending one character.

Why is this so?

Comment: Please copy the code as text instead of bad screen dumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect an end of line character is send (probably \n or \r, see comment of Edgar Bonet), or an end of string (0 character).

You can easily find it out by printing the integer value of the character:

```
char c = serial.read();
Serial.print((int) c);
```

Comment: Actually '\n' = 10 (a.k.a. LF, line feed, new line), not to be confused with '\r' = 13 (CR, carriage return). And yes, it's a '\n', as attested by the selection “Newline” on the drop-down menu at the bottom. The other options of this menu are “No line ending”, “Carriage return” and “Both NL and CR”. Note that the last options sends CR before LF.

Comment: @EdgarBonet Thanks for your clarification, I put a forward to your comment. It's always better to check the exact character(s) which ends a line.